# Electrum. Payto argument from_addr

Tags: address, electrum

I need to specify address to send from.
I want to use option createnewaddress. And then send money from this addresse useing payto and from_addr option.
When I do like that, i got error message not enough funds.
When i do payto without argument, it use first unused address (that i create before with createnewaddress).
How can i send payment from specified address ? Or transfer amount on specified address.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough funds usually means that you've confused the unit of account i.e. mbtc vs. btc or you're not accounting for transaction fees including 2fa fees if you have a 2fa wallet. I suggest you use the exclamation point in place of a numeric amount to see what is the max amount you can send. Decoding the generated transaction should be illuminating.